Can I post AI generated content here?
I found an answer to my question using an AI system.  It solved my problem, and so may solve the same problem for others. Can I post that as an answer here?

Yes, you may.  However, you are expected to state clearly the source of the information (including the fact that it is AI generated).
If you do not do this and it is determined that the content was AI generated, your post will be deleted and you risk being banned from posting for a period of time.
It would also be appreciated if you confirmed in detail how you applied the answer, and tried to edit out irrelevant details.  AI's can be exhaustively long winded, which is not necessarily a bad thing, but please try to avoid cut n' pasting that verbatim and apply some focus. Posts which abide by the attribution rule above are still subject to normal evaluation and if they do not demonstrate sufficient thought will not be received well.
